# Can you drag-and-drop a TextView when it is in a child of a TableLayout?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-tablelayout

My code is as followed thus far, as I am testing it out:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
TableLayout table;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
    setStuff();
    setStuff2();
    setStuff3();  
}

public void setStuff() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    TextView view = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_text, table, false);
    view.setText("First");
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(table.getChildCount()));
    view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            v.startDrag(ClipData.newPlainText("index", v.getTag().toString()), new View.DragShadowBuilder(v), null, 0);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "index you are clicking on is "+v.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    table.addView(view);
}
public void setStuff2() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    TextView view = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_text, table, false);
    view.setText("Second");
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(table.getChildCount()));
    table.addView(view);
}
public void setStuff3() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    TextView view = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_text, table, false);
    view.setText("Three");
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(table.getChildCount()));
    table.addView(view);
}


protected class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        //Stuff to check the event action cases

        return false;
    }

}//end of MyDragListener
```

Now when I long press the first item, it runs correctly because I get the Toast notification. I do not see the DragShadow though, which I am suppose to see. My guess is that because it is part of the TableLayout, it might be causing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is awkward, but I think I just figured out why it did not let me drag and drop the `TextView`. I don't really know exactly why, but I am completely guessing that `startDrag()` is limited to non-root level `View`s that are binded to other `View`s. So, My xml was this:

**Originally**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/da_text"></TextView>
```

**Edit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/da_text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hopefully this helps someone else. There aren't many questions and even less answers on Drag-n-Drop, so it won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

A TableView normally needs TableRows to fill it. If you put your TextView in a TableRow and this TableRow in  your TableView you can drag and drop the TextView wherever you want, provided that you used the right code for the OnDragListeners etc. and of course you cant drag and drop a textview that is not set in a layout because there is no place where you can drop it...